# Merge multiple spreadsheets with pd.merge

Tags: python, pandas, merge, spreadsheet, xlsx

I am trying to merge multiple spreadsheets together on Python. I have the same header titles for each column in the same order with the same data types. The only differences between the four are the actual data points in the cell. Here's what I mean

**df1**:

| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | M | 1 |
| Y | B | T | 2 |

**df2**:

| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G | J | H | 5 |
| B | Q | L | 8 |

**df3**:

| Header 1 | Header 2 | Header 3 | Header 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| E | U | D | 6 |
| Z | P | S | 3 |

The `dtypes` for the dfs are as follows:

- Header 1: object
- Header 2: object
- Header 3: object
- Header 4: float

I basically just want to stack the data from all of the data frames on top of one another, like this:

| Header 1 | Header 2 |
| --- | --- |
| X | A |
| Y | B |
| G | J |
| B | Q |
| E | U |
| Z | P |

...and so on for header 3 & 4. Any way I can do this with pd.merge?

Comment: use `df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])`, and find the target columns you wanted. `df[['Header 1', 'Header2']]`

Comment: What you're looking for is `pd.concat()`

Answer (score 0):

Try df4=df1.merge(df2,on="outer")

```
followed by

`df4.merge(df3,on="outer")
```

[image]